# Extra space behind month for \today with \usepackage[norsk]{babel} in December

Tags: spacing, titles, babel

When using `\today` and `\usepackage[norsk]{babel}` (`babel <v3.8l>`) in December there is an extra space behind the month name. How do I get around this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\begin{document}
\day12\month12\year2011
\today

12. desember 2011
\end{document}
```

[image: 12. desember 2011]

---

### Note 1

Javier Bezos [writes](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=babel/4199) that the issue is fixed in the forthcoming `babel`, version 3.9.

### Note 2

Version 3.9 of `babel` was released March 2013.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file `norsk.dtx` contains the following definition for `\today`:

```
\def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    januar\or februar\or mars\or april\or mai\or juni\or
    juli\or august\or september\or oktober\or november\or desember
    \fi
    \space\number\year}
```

and there's a spurious blank space generating the extra space; if you want to suppress the space, you need to add the following lines to the preamble of your document

```
\AtBeginDocument{\def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    januar\or februar\or mars\or april\or mai\or juni\or
    juli\or august\or september\or oktober\or november\or desember%
    \fi
    \space\number\year}}
```

I think this should be reported to the maintainer of the `norsk` module for `babel`.

Answer (score 11):

It's a bit too late, but it's still worth adding this note.

When only Norsk is involved, redefining `\today` at begin document is fine. However, with two or more languages it's not correct: any command `\selectlanguage{norsk}` would resurrect the buggy definition.

The safest way to proceed is to say

```
\def\datenorsk{\def\today{\number\day.~\ifcase\month\or
    januar\or februar\or mars\or april\or mai\or juni\or
    juli\or august\or september\or oktober\or november\or desember\fi
    \space\number\year}}
```

because among the duties of `\selectlanguage{norsk}` is to issue `\datenorsk`. If this code is in the preamble, all will be well. When the `norsk.ldf` file will be corrected, the code will do no harm either.